# Unclear error while trying to connect to Zend with smarty and apache log4php

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty, zend-autoloader, spl-autoloader

I'm using zend framework with log4php and smarty, I've encountered the following problem while trying to run bootstrap of Zend.

This is the error I get:

```
PHP Warning: require_once(Smarty.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /var/www/html/kb/vaserver/VaDaemon/config.php on line 37 pid    
6049
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Smarty.php'
```

I think my problem is quite similar to the following mentioned [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4PHP-129), however this bug was already solved and fixed and I saw the fix is similar to what James was writing there.
Anyway this is not working as you can see , so I wonder what else should I try.

Here is my config.php code:

/**
 *

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

// The custom error handlers that ship with PHP Simple Daemon respect all PHP INI error settings.
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/phpcli');
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

// Define a simple Auto Loader:
// Add the current application and the PHP Simple Daemon ./Core library to the existing include path
// Then set an __autoload function that uses Zend Framework naming conventions.
define("VA_BASE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));              

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(   
    realpath(VA_BASE_PATH . '/AbstractLayer/'), 
    realpath(VA_BASE_PATH), 
    realpath(VA_BASE_PATH . '/../'),
    realpath(VA_BASE_PATH . '/../Core'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

function vaDaemon_Autoloader($class_name)
{
    $class_name = str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);
    $class_name = str_replace('_', '/', $class_name);
    require_once "$class_name.php"; // **line 37 as mentioned above in error** 
}

spl_autoload_register('vaDaemon_Autoloader');

function pathify($class_name) {
    return str_replace("_", "/", $class_name) . ".php";
}
```

Comment: This is exactly as it says in the error.  The file was not found/not readable.  You should confirm the files path and the use of require_once

Comment: Can you be more specific, where should I add the paths to, maybe in the above set_include_path function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed ZF2 using Composer, it'll make your life easier if you install log4php and Smarty with it as well. Update your `composer.json` and add update your existing require section to add the two other libraries to it:

```
"require": {
    "apache/log4php": "2.3.0",
    "smarty/smarty": "3.1.19"
}
```

Then run `php composer.phar install`. Then composer can handle the autoloading and you don't need to do anything with include paths or `spl_autoload_register()`.